# PCB antenna track and SMA connector controlled impedance

Tags: pcb, impedance, gsm, ground-plane

I designed a pcb for GSM module, using all the specifications given by the manufacturer, to have a controlled impedance. But there is a small detail that escapes me and that is not documented. When the trace of the antenna arrives at the SMA connector, should the ground plane be opened or should I continue to keep a distance as for the whole trace? Some manufacturers, with the same module, open the ground plane to the maximum, others keep it constant.

What is the correct solution? [image]

I add a photo to explain better.

Thank you all and sorry for my english

Comment: welcome here! Your English is excellent, don't worry!

Comment: Is the connector mounted on the top side or the bottom side? And do you have any freedom to change it? What frequency band are your signals?

Comment: In picture 1, there will definitely be an impedance change as the trace enters the area under the connector where the ground plane is cut back.  How much of a problem that will be at the highest GSM frequency (1.9 GHz, I think), I can't say.

Comment: Also, what's on the next layer down (into the page) under the trace and the connector region.

Comment: And on figure 2, I would have thought they would place the via stitching right next to the trace on the GND plane, not pulled back like it's shown.

Comment: I vote for design 1. The impedance of the microstrip portion is more dependent on the other, ground plane layer, than the flooded surround on the same layer as the strip. And design 2 would create a partial short at the end of the coax segment. In either case I doubt you’ll see any problem because the transition is so short.

Comment: Thank you to all for your answer and questions..

Comment: Thank you to all for your answer and questions.. Connector is mounted on ground plane side so is not influent for impedance . I think is better to use the figure 2, but my doubts come from the configuration of many board on market, all with big space under connector...

Comment: What does the bottom of the connector look like? The part that will be near the PCB? If it is dielectric, then I would suggest to open ground. If it is metal then close ground.

Answer (score 1):

For 1.5GHz with a 1/4Wave ~ 3cm and the SMT radius about 10% of this , it is unlikely to make a difference at this frequency so filling it will reduce ingress at shorter wavelengths, yet one wants to avoid solder bridges under the holes. In the end, it doesn't make a huge difference for GSM but would for higher frequencies.  Only test validation will know for sure.

### Background info

Track impedance \$Z_O=\sqrt{\dfrac{L}{C}}\$ and this depends on conductor/dielectric ratios for L/G and L/H or L/H/G ratios.

Coplanar gaps have less effect on C than dielectric gaps between trace and ground plane underneath.

I see no reason for Figure 1 as that raises the impedance up to 50% with a large increase in W/G. Although I do see a reason for preventing a solder bridge.

Guarded trace W/G=5/1  Coplanar Gap = 20% of Width

This is only for FR4.

Under SMT W/G = 0.20 or a 1-side only change in gap, this amounts to an increase of 4/0.2 or 20:1  with a possible rise of 50% in impedance.

[image]

I might consider a compromise but the Height of dielectric and effective Dk of  PCB are unknown and may be different in each example you saw. Yet it's the ratios that matter in discontinuities for relative changes.

[image]

These differences will be manifested by S parameters on the harmonics of the signals or interference well above GSM band.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will try with two different prototypes. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: It depends on your expected performance above the GSM band.

Answer (score 0):

The connector vendor likely provides PCB footprints as a free service if you ask. I agree that it probably doesn’t matter in this case, but when faced with this I got a footprint from the vendor, based on my PCB stack-up, and used that. I include a thru line with connectors on each side on the PCB panel somewhere and measure I/O VSWR and insertion loss to verify how close the vendor got to 50 ohms and how much reflection I get from the footprints.

Best luck.